# SAP Business objects how to create different kinds of join between different data providers

Tags: business-objects

I have two data providers. One is a universe, one is an excel file. Excel file has column ID. I want to find ID, JOB_ID, Cost.

I have created a merged dimension:- ID. When I create report with ID and Cost, I'm getting an outer joined result which is what I want. But when I add another attribute from universe it is being inner joined result.

Where can I control this feature?

Comment: Is Cost a Measure or Dimension?

Comment: Cost is a measure. When I add another dimension like JOB_ID etc it is returning innner join. If I have only ID and cost, I get left join which is what I wanted for all scenarios

Comment: I missed the fact that this is a zero-to-many relationship. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked :) I'm a beginner in SAP BO thought it would be something to do with join defined in universe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ever so close. Here are the basics when working with a zero or one to many relationships. Credit for this goes to this [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/12/10/merging-queries-with-a-1-to-n-relationship/). I am copying it here if perchance that link goes dead.

> As a rule of thumb , when trying to merge DP’s with a 1xN relationship
>   :
>
> 1. Merge the common fields
> 2. Use the dimension coming from the N side query
> 3. Create detail variables from the 1 side query for each dimension needed with associated dimension equal the merged dimension
> 4. Check "Show rows with empty dimension values" on Table formatting for each table using dimensions coming from both queries.

Here is a screen shot to highlight where to find the setting in step #4.

[image]